# Indexed view and T-sql that give same results as DISTINCT in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, indexed-view

I want to create indexed view **MyView** with such t-sql

```
Select 
    o.Theme_ID as Theme_ID,
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, o.Object_CreationDate), 0) as Objext_CreationDate,
    Count_BIG(*) as ObjectCount,   o.Object_Tonality from [dbo].Object o
inner join [dbo].Theme t on o.Theme_ID = t.Theme_ID
inner join [dbo].[ThemeWorkplace] tw on t.Theme_ID = tw.Theme_ID
inner join [dbo].Workplace w on w.Workplace_ID = tw.Workplace_ID
 ... where t.Theme_DeletedMark = 0
 AND (w.Workplace_AccessType = 1 OR w.Workplace_AccessType = 8)
 AND Object_DeletedMark = 0 ...
 Group BY o.Theme_ID,o.Object_Tonality, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, o.Object_CreationDate), 0)
```

This t-sql works fine and allows to set a clustered index on **MyView**.

The problem is that table `ThemeWorkplace` contains several records with same `Theme_ID`.
AND even I use `GROUP BY`  - I get in `Object_Count` value that
equals: (real `Object_Count` value) * count(`Theme_ID` in `ThemeWorkplace` ).

I can't use `DISTINCT` word in t-sql, because in this case it is impossible to create index on view.

What is a suggestion to get correct results in my view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noted, there are significant restrictions on creating an indexed view. The techniques that might help you here, such as distinct or a subquery are prohibited. I think you'll need to sacrifice materializing the view in this particular case.